# GitLab CI scheduled pipeline not running on master

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a scheduled pipeline that copies some data from one server to another once a day.

The pipeline works fine on all branches but doesn't start if I select `master` branch (default branch) as the `target branch`.

I have tried on an exact copy of `master` and it worked fine.

I though it could be because `master` is protected but I tried on a protected copy of master and it worked.

I'm really not sure what's going on. When I click the "play" button next to the scheduled pipeline and it says that the job was successfully scheduled, but I cannot see any job in the job list.

Here some details on the `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```yaml
stages:
  - copy_data
  - linting
  - test
  - deploy


lint:
  needs: []
  stage: linting
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'
      changes:
        - "my_project/**/*.py"
  script:
    - ...

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ...
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'

copy_database:on-schedule:
  stage: copy_data
  needs: []
  only:
    - schedules
    - $COPY_DB # this is set in the pipeline menu on gitlab
  script:
    - ...
  timeout: 3h
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem! The issue is that gitlab was saying `Successfully scheduled a pipeline to run. Go to the Pipelines page for details.` while in reality there was an error.

To debug it I used the trick described [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/218374#note_533785295) that is to run a manual pipeline and set `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE = "schedule"`. Running the pipeline in this way returned the error message and I was able to fix the issue.

---

If you are wondering what the error was, here is some more detail.

I had two pipelines optionally running on the master branch:

```
prepare_release:
  stage: prepare_release
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: manual
  script:
    - ...

create_release:
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  stage: release
  needs:
    - job: prepare_release
      artifacts: true
  rules:
     // HERE THERE SHOULD BE A RULE TO PREVENT THIS FROM RUNNING ON SCHEDULE
       // - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
    //  when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
  script:
    - ...
```

The second pipeline did not have a

```
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
      when: never
```

And therefore tried running on the schedule. However since it needs the previous one and that wasn’t created, it errors.
Mi mistake was to assume that the "needs" would take into account this rule from the parent job.

Comment: IMHO it should be a GitLab bug, when it says the pipeline run "successfully" while it errors under the hood. Is there a GitLab version when it is fixed?

Comment: To add on your answer, another option to skip a job on `schedules` is to add:
`
  except:
    - schedules
`

Comment: Thanks for the tip on running a manual pipeline! Life saver

Comment: Good grief. Thank you so much for the manual pipeline tip. I was tearing my hair out.

Comment: @Orb Indeed, it would make sense for Gitlab to at least write a "Empty pipeline" entry in the pipeline execution log or something, so we at least know the scheduling happened.

Comment: One more pitfall is that `except: schedules` is not affected if you pass in the `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` variable. So you should convert your conditions to `except: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"` first.

Answer (score 4):

It is because it is protected, but not *just* because it is protected. The ability to [create pipelines on a protected branch](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html#running-pipelines-on-protected-branches) is determined by the user's ability to merge or push to that branch. A scheduled pipeline is run with the permissions of the schedule owner ([initially, the user who created it)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html#taking-ownership).

You either need to have your user given merge/push access on master, or have another user with that permission to take ownership of the schedule.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I don't think that's the issue. I'm the owner of the pipeline and have all permissions on that branch. I have tried unprotecting the `master` branch but it still does not work. I have a feeling it's due to other jobs having rules based on `$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH` but I can't see what's wrong with it...

Answer (score 2):

```
copy_database:on-schedule:
  stage: copy_data
  needs: []
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule" || $COPY_DB
      when: always
  script:
    ...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I've tried this and unfortunately it still doesn't run on `master` (it works on other branches though...)

Comment: Did you try this on the master branch?
even running with COPY_BD defined?

Comment: Yeah, I did but no luck :/

Comment: Just created a project with the working feature:  

https://gitlab.com/MoLt1eS/cron-stackoverflow-answer  



Regular pipeline after comiting to master:   
https://gitlab.com/MoLt1eS/cron-stackoverflow-answer/-/pipelines/251590363

Cron working as intended every 5 min, using master branch:
https://gitlab.com/MoLt1eS/cron-stackoverflow-answer/-/pipelines/251590933

Comment: Cron config:
https://gitlab.com/MoLt1eS/cron-stackoverflow-answer/-/pipeline_schedules

(I will disable after a few more runs)

Comment: Config screnshot: https://imgur.com/5KejvDJ  
@giuppep I hope this helps you moving foward

Comment: Thanks for the help @MoLt1eS. I have now found the solution if you are interested (see accepted answer).

Answer (score 0):

Look in your `gitlab-ci.yml` for this entry:

```
  only:
  - master
```

And edit accordingly ; Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, it was that while the schedule was on target branch `master`, the default branch of ther repo had recently been renamed to `main`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a scheduled pipeline not running.

This is the best way to debug (as of gitlab 15.8):

- As an admin, impersonate the user that owns the schedule.
- `Leave Admin Mode` (if you're still in admin mode after impersonating). This is important because projects required by the pipeline may not be accessible to the user without admin mode.
- Go to `CI/CD` -> `Pipelines` -> `Run pipeline`.
- Trigger pipeline with the same settings used in the schedule, but make sure to add variable `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` with value `schedule`.

An error message should indicate the underlying problem now.

PS: Running the pipeline from `CI/CD` -> `Schedules` may lie to you and say

> Successfully scheduled a pipeline to run. …

… even though GitLab fails to schedule it.